# What is the difference between NUL and NULL?

Tags: c

`NULL` is a macro defined in `<stddef.h>` for the `null pointer`; it can be defined as `((void*)0)`. `NULL` is the name of the first character in the `ASCII` character set. What is the difference between them?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293634/2173917) before answering.

Comment: Why is it marked as duplicate? Perhaps the question was badly written but this is not a duplicate. The other thread doesn't have `NUL` in its title.

Answer (score 8):

NULL and NUL are of the same concept: They both represent the absence of a value. The only difference is - as you said - NULL is a macro in  whereas NUL is the name given to the first ASCII character. The only scenario you are likely to come across a macro called NUL is something like this:

```
#define NUL '\0'
```

Comment: If you do, it might look like this: `#define NUL  '\0'`

Comment: @chqrlie: Good point. Appropriate changes made

Answer (score 2):

There is no such term as `NUL` in the C Standard. In the C Standard there are used the following terms

```
null character (\0)
NULL macro
null pointer
null pointer constant
null preprocessing directive
null statement
null wide character
```

For example

> ...A byte with all bits set to 0, called the **null character**, shall
>   exist in the basic execution character set; it is used to terminate a
>   character string.

Or

> 3 An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an
>   expression cast to type void *, is called a **null pointer
>   constant**.66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer
>   type, the resulting pointer, called a **null pointer**, is guaranteed
>   to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `0`, `NULL`, `'\0'` and `L'\0'` are somewhat different:

`sizeof(NULL)` is the same as `sizeof(void*)`, which is usually `8` on 64 bit Intel systems.

`sizeof(0)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, which is commonly still `4` on common 64 bit Intel systems.

`sizeof('\0')` is also the same as `sizeof(int)` in `C`, but is the same as `sizeof(char)` in `C++` which has the value `1` by definition and is most likely different from `sizeof(int)`.

`sizeof(L'\0')` is the same as `sizeof(wchar_t)`, which is implementation defined.

Surprisingly, in `C`, you may have `sizeof(L'\0') < sizeof('\0')`

Comment: In C++ a `char` will never be of the same size as an `int` because `char`s are always 1 byte, and `int`s are always at least 2 bytes.

Comment: This makes sense as C++ must be able to distinguish between `char` and `int`, but even on systems where `sizeof(int) == 1`, `int` and `char` are distinct types in `C`, so why have this extra constraint?