# is 'NUL' a name or abreviation in ASCII?

Tags: ascii

to my understanding, in ASCII NUL is not a name, it's an abreviation. Is this correct?

1. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string#firstHeading) it says that the ASCII NULL character is called
   NUL.
2. In [comment 2962254](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911089/null-terminating-a-string#comment-2962254), Matteo Italia states that the NULL character is not called NULL.
3. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the table in "Character groups", the name is "NULL", abreviated "NUL"
4. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) NUL is an abreviation, not a name
5. in [answer 30121329](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121241/what-is-the-difference-between-nul-and-null#answer-30121329): «NUL is the name given to the first ASCII character.»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"NUL" is short for "NULL". Quoting [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm), which lists all control characters as "8.3.xx acr - name":

> **8.3.88 NUL - NULL**
> Notation: (C0)
> Representation: 00/00
>
> NUL is used for media-fill or time-fill. NUL characters may be inserted into, or removed from, a data stream without affecting the information content of that stream, but such action may affect the information layout and/or the control of equipment.

Now, about your question:

> In wikipedia it says that the ASCII NULL character is called NUL.

This is not what Wikipedia says. It says the ASCII null (lowercase!) character is called NUL. "Null character" is a term that applies to all character encodings, "NULL character" is not.

Wikipedia is correct, as there is nothing wrong with referring to this character by its official acronym.

> In comment 2962254, Matteo Italia states that the NULL character is not called NULL.

He is wrong about that.

> here, the table in "Character groups", the name is "NULL", abreviated "NUL"
> here NUL is an abreviation, not a name

These are both correct.

> in answer 30121329: «NUL is the name given to the first ASCII character.»

This is technically incorrect, but for all practical purposes correct. The acronyms are better known than the official names, and I don't see much of a problem in treating those acronyms as names.

Comment: FMI: I am used to read/write NULL uppercase in **code**. In this case it is defined by the context it relates to and may or may not be case insensitive. This does not apply to **terminologies**, though.

Comment: Actually the 7-bit character encoding known as ASCII (aka ISO-646, aka ANSI-X3.4) is specified by ECMA-6, which calls the two or three letter codes for characters _acronyms_ (§5.3:  "_This ECMA Standard assigns a unique name to each character.  In addition, it specifies an acronym for each control character and for the characters SPACE and DELETE, and a graphic symbol for each graphic character_").    (ECMA-48 defines the _use_ of the control characters, but does not _specify_ their names or acronyms or values or graphic symbols.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `nul`, is an abbreviation of `null`.

Not a particularly shortened version as it’s only shorter by one character, but as ASCII characters are limited to 3, so there isn’t much choice really.

The uppercase standard of `NUL` is a convention of ASCII, for example, `TAB`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate about the uppercase standard?